# Seeking UML Diagrams for Ecommerce CMS Data Model and Guidance on Microservices Architecture

Tags: angular, spring, microservices, e-commerce, datamodel

I'm a university student working on a final thesis project which involves developing a full-stack ecommerce CMS. I am using Angular on the frontend and Spring on the backend. The goal is to create a flexible webshop capable of selling a diverse range of products.

Given the commonality of such a project, I'm certain that robust, tried-and-tested data models must exist that have resolved most of the edge cases associated with constructing a generic ecommerce site. Therefore, I'm looking for UML diagrams or other resources that could help illustrate an efficient and robust data model for this purpose.

Additionally, I'm interested in understanding how to break down this concept into microservices, to ensure scalability and maintainability of the project.

I have conceptualized a data model for this ecommerce system, but given my relative inexperience, I want to ensure that it's robust and capable of handling diverse products without running into significant edge cases. I'm hoping to find existing models or diagrams that have been successfully employed in similar projects, from which I could learn and adapt for my use case.

I also haven't started implementing the microservices architecture yet, and I'm expecting there to be well-established methods or patterns that could guide me in fragmenting the system efficiently.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.